# How would I check for change of state of in-memory database in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack, sqlite-net, sqlite.net

I am using an SQLite in-memory database, via OrmLite, for integration tests in ServiceStack.
I'd like to be able to confirm there has been no change of state in the Database between tests. Is there any easy way to do this? Maybe the equivalent of hashing? Or a flag that indicates updates have happened?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There's no global check in SQLite that could be used to determine whether there's been any state changes AFAIK.

It wont be able to detect updated rows but you could compare a snapshot of all the tables and their row counts with [GetTableNamesWithRowCounts](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/#gettablenames-and-gettablenameswithrowcounts-apis).

```
var tablesWithRowCounts = db.GetTableNamesWithRowCounts(live:true);
```